# $\lbrace D^+ f < c \rbrace$ is measurable when $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous and $$D^+f(x) = \limsup_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
Is the set $$\lbrace x \in [a,b] : D^+ f(x) < c \rbrace$$ Lebesgue measurable $\forall c \in \mathbb R$?

---

I can rewrite
$$ D^+f(x) = \limsup_{n} n(f(x+1/n) - f(x)). $$
But the $\limsup$ of measurable functions ($f$ is measurable) is still measurable, therefore the thesis.

Is this simple reasoning correct?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry but the identity $ D^+f(x) = \limsup\limits_{n} n(f(x+1/n) - f(x))$ is not true in general.

Comment: Instead, use the sup over all rationals $u$ with $|u|<1/n$.

Comment: So I understand I could have a different value by using different "paths" to approach $0$; but does taking all rationals guarantees that I will consider all these "paths"? This is due to the continuity I guess

Answer (score 1):

The supremum of a countable family of measurable functions is measurable. So is the infimum. Both follow from the fact that sub-level sets are countable unions (resp. intersections).

So, how to express $D^+f$ by means of such operations? Introduce 
$$
f_{h} = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$
Take the supremum over all rational $h$ such that $0<h<1/n$. By virtue of continuity of $f$, this gives the same result as taking supremum over all real numbers in $(0,1/n)$.

Then take the infimum over $n$ to get $D^+f$.